Ray tracing artifacts along facet edges
I have a CPU-ray tracer and have been struggling to deal with artifacts along facet edges near the terminator (I believe this is a fairly common issue).  These were the artifacts I was getting originally:

This problem (the so-called "shadow terminator problem") is because the shading normals (which are interpolated for smooth shading) vary continuously while the intersection point is constrained to the still flat faces of each triangle, leading to jump discontinuities in the shadow contingent on the face geometry, rather than the interpolated normal.
A possible solution therefore, would be (for convex surfaces) to interpolate the intersection point similar to how the normals are being interpolated.  This GLSL code snippet shows an approach for doing this:  https://gist.github.com/pixnblox/5e64b0724c186313bc7b6ce096b08820
I have adapted the code for my purposes:
template <IsFloat TFloat>
vec3<TFloat> projectOnPlane(vec3<TFloat> position, vec3<TFloat> origin, Normal normal)
{
    if constexpr (std::same_as<TFloat, double>) {
        vec3<TFloat> n{ normal[0], normal[1], normal[2] };
        return position - dot(position - origin, n) * n;
    }
    else {
        return position - dot(position - origin, normal) * normal;
    }
}

template <IsFloat TFloat, IsColor TColor>
inline vec3<TFloat> computeShadingPoint(const vec3<TFloat>& intersection, const std::array<Vertex<TFloat, TColor>, 3>& vert, const std::array<TFloat, 3>& w, const Normal& shadingNormal)
{
    // Project the geometric position (inside the triangle) to the planes defined by the vertex
    // positions and normals.
    vec3<TFloat> p0 = projectOnPlane(intersection, vert[0].position, vert[0].normal);
    vec3<TFloat> p1 = projectOnPlane(intersection, vert[1].position, vert[1].normal);
    vec3<TFloat> p2 = projectOnPlane(intersection, vert[2].position, vert[2].normal);

    // Interpolate the projected positions using the barycentric coordinates, which gives the
    // shading position.
    vec3<TFloat> shadingPoint = p0 * w[0] + p1 * w[1] + p2 * w[2];

    // Return the shading position for a convex triangle, where the shading point is above the
    // triangle based on the shading normal. Otherwise use the geometric position.
    vec3<float> diff = shadingPoint - intersection;
    bool convex = dot(diff, shadingNormal) > 0;
    return convex ? shadingPoint : intersection;
};

(The templating is because my ray-tracer supports single and double precision, as well as "colors" with more than 3 wavelengths.  I do not believe this is any way related to the problem at hand)
If I use this to update the intersection point for all future bounce/shadow rays, it gets rid of the worst of the artifacts, but some still remain right along the facet edges.

If I use the newly adjusted intersection point ONLY for shadow rays, and not subsequent bounce rays, the artifacts become worse:

Blender, and other rendering engines I've tried with the same scene, do not exhibit these artifacts at all.  These artifacts also don't show up on spheres, so I believe it is a problem with concave surfaces.  Looking closely at the models, it appears that the artifacts occur on edges that represent a concave curve (the neck of the chess pieces here tapering inwards).
Are there ways to address these artifacts?  They are very minor, and only impact low-poly models which aren't particularly common for my work, but its still something I'd like to address.
